# Using Models and Entities in MVP pattern

Tags: c#, object-oriented, .net, winforms, mvp

I'm a beginner in MVP design pattern and In a MVP triad, I have

**Model** - `AdvanceInfo`

**View** - `AdvanceForm`

**Presenter** - `AdvancePresneter`

and **Entity class** `Advance` as follows.

```
 public class Advance
{
    public int AdvanceID { get; set; }
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceEnteredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceProcessDate { get; set; }
}
```

So Should my `model` be as follows...

```
class AdvanceInfo 
{
    public int AdvanceID  { get { return Advance.AdvanceID; } }
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get { return Advance.AdvanceAmount; } set { Advance.AdvanceAmount = value; } }
    public DateTime AdvanceEnteredDate  { get { return Advance.AdvanceEnteredDate; } set { Advance.AdvanceEnteredDate = value; } }

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string NameWithInitials { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountName { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }

    public Advance Advance = new Advance();
}
```

or else...

```
class AdvanceInfo 
{
    public int AdvanceID { get; set; }
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string NameWithInitials { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountName { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceEnteredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceProcessDate { get; set; }

}
```

Note: 
* I'm using entity class `Advance` as an aggregate class in `DeductionInfo` class as well.
* I'm not using any frameworks like EF. Only VS. (Since this is academic purpose project)

I hope my question is clear; actually what I want to know is how entity classes are used to build model? or else can we use Model classes alone?

Comment: I'm a "noob" in .net, what `VS` stand for ?

Comment: I meant Visual Studio ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're referring to as *Model classes*, I think you're over-thinking it.

I'd go with the *else* snippet, the POCO (*Plain Old CLR Object*) that does nothing but exposing auto-properties. The snippet that exposes a `public Advance` field doesn't look right. **Do not** expose public fields; a class should expose *properties*, not *fields*.

Your remark about *only using VS* isn't clear either: if you're not using EF, that's fine, but this means your data access code is using *some data access library* - Visual Studio isn't one, it's your IDE; if you're using things under `System.Data`, you're using **ADO.NET**.

If I understand correctly what you're doing, you have a bunch of tables/entities that have columns/properties in common, and you're wondering if *composition* would be better than repeating the properties on all classes. You forgot an option: *inheritance*.

*Composition* is normally favored over *inheritance*, but in the case of POCO classes composition can greatly complicate matters, and if you're instantiating your POCO's from an `SqlReader` it doesn't really matter *how* that's done, since you completely own the process.

Things are different with EF - *composition* would lead to a database model similar to this:

[image: YUML diagram: [Advance]1-0..1>[AdvanceInfo]|[Advance]1-0..1>[DeductionInfo]]

With *inheritance*, you have this (I hope I got the UML right):

[image: YUML diagram: [Advance]<>->[AdvanceInfo]|[Advance]<>->[DeductionInfo]]

Which involves 3 classes, but works off only 2 tables: `Advance` isn't really an entity, it's just a *base class* with properties that are common to `DeductionInfo` and `AdvanceInfo`.

Hence, *if what you intend to do is to model 2 tables*, I'd do this:

```
public abstract class AdvanceBase
{
    public int AdvanceID { get; set; }
    public decimal AdvanceAmount { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceEnteredDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime AdvanceProcessDate { get; set; }
}
```

The class is made `abstract`, to enforce the concept that such a class shouldn't be instantiated and serve as a base class for derived types instead:

```
public class AdvanceInfo : AdvanceBase
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string NameWithInitials { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountName { get; set; }
    public string BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The `AdvanceInfo` class inherits the `AdvanceID` and everything else from `AdvanceBase`, so you don't need to specify them again.

Then you'll have:

```
public class DeductionInfo : AdvanceBase
{
    /* DeductionInfo members */
}
```

And here also, the class will inherit the `AdvanceBase` members so you only need to code the `DeductionInfo`-specific members in that class.

And if/when you switch to EF, you can reuse the exact same POCO classes as *entities*, without changing anything.

Side note, I think the naming of the classes is somewhat bad - I'd call `AdvanceInfo` just `Advance`, and `DeductionInfo` would be simply `Deduction`.

Comment: Nice answer and I think I got the point. but I'm little confused-> People would view a POCO as a plain old class that doesn't try to be part of the trendy pattern set, just like my `Advance` class. But in your example classes (used inheritance) no POCO classes and you favored inheritance over composition in this case. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah, just presenting it as a *possibility* though. Like I said I'd go with the *else* snippet ;) I often use inheritance with my POCO's, I find it useful for stuffing `Id`, `DateCreated` and `DateUpdated` properties (I call that type `EntityBase`). I'm not sure I'd use it for anything else, like *properties that are common to a group of entities*. Perhaps I should put that in the answer as well...

Comment: One thing to clarify. In your `AdvanceInfo` class derived from `AdvanceBase`, it has properties `EmployeeID`, `EmployeeName` etc. which are actually belonged to `Employee` class. So don't we have to derived from That class too without re declaring same? Is that the best practice?

Comment: ALSO in all the places we use `EmployeeID` property, should we derive it from `Employee` class? Thank you!